# Comparar textos escritos em ordens diferentes

Tags: r, texto

Possuo uma tabela onde cada linha é um texto e esses textos são escritos em ordens diferentes porem significam a mesma coisa, gostaria de uma forma de comparar. Exemplo de base:

`lista <- data.frame(frutas = c("banana, abacate, laranja","limao, abacate","laranja, banana, abacate"))`

A linha 1 e 3 são iguais, o ideal é uma coluna que indique que essas linhas são iguais.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duas ideias. Para ambas, primeiro separar e ordenar os elementos de cada string de texto em uma lista. Vou usar um exemplo modificado para incluir mais de duas linhas equivalentes e combinação parcial.

```
df <- data.frame(frutas = c(
  "banana, abacate, laranja",
  "limao, abacate",
  "laranja, banana, abacate",
  "abacate, laranja, banana",
  "laranja, banana"))

lfrutas <- lapply(strsplit(df$frutas, ", "), sort)
```

### Coluna indicando quais linhas são iguais

A ideia:

- usar `apply` para comparar cada elemento da lista com os demais, com `which` para determinar o número (correspondente às linhas)
- fazer isso em um loop, eliminando do resultado o número da linha atual

```
for (i in seq_along(lfrutas)) {
  l <- which(sapply(lfrutas, function(x) identical(lfrutas[[i]], x)))
  df$igual_linha[i] <- paste0(l[l != i], collapse = ",")
}

df
#>                     frutas igual_linha
#> 1 banana, abacate, laranja         3,4
#> 2           limao, abacate
#> 3 laranja, banana, abacate         1,4
#> 4 abacate, laranja, banana         1,3
#> 5          laranja, banana
```

### Matriz de comparações

Ideia: usar as funções da família `apply` para comparar todos os elementos da lista entre si, gerando uma matriz com as comparações:

```
mapply(function(y) sapply(lfrutas, function(x) identical(x, y)), lfrutas)
#>       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
#> [1,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#> [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [3,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#> [4,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#> [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 4):

Uma solução é ordenar cada uma das strings e compará-las duas a duas.

```r
lista <- data.frame(frutas = c("banana, abacate, laranja","limao, abacate","laranja, banana, abacate"))

ltemp <- sapply(strsplit(lista$frutas, ""), \(x) {
  trimws(paste(sort(x), collapse = ""))
})
res <- combn(ltemp, 2, \(x) x[[1]] == x[[2]])
rm(ltemp)
setNames(res, combn(length(res), 2, \(x) paste(x, collapse = ".")))
#>   1.2   1.3   2.3 
#> FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

### Edição

No seguimento da resposta do [Carlos Eduardo Lagosta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/559842/82237), pode-se usar `outer` para criar uma matrix lógica de comparações.

```r
lista <- data.frame(frutas = c("banana, abacate, laranja","limao, abacate","laranja, banana, abacate"))

ltemp <- sapply(strsplit(lista$frutas, ""), \(x) {
  trimws(paste(sort(x), collapse = ""))
})

outer(ltemp, ltemp, `==`)
#>       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#> [1,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#> [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#> [3,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Com os dados aumentados da mesma resposta.

```r
df <- data.frame(frutas = c(
  "banana, abacate, laranja",
  "limao, abacate",
  "laranja, banana, abacate",
  "abacate, laranja, banana",
  "laranja, banana"))
ltemp2 <- sapply(strsplit(df$frutas, ""), \(x) {
  trimws(paste(sort(x), collapse = ""))
})

outer(ltemp2, ltemp2, `==`)
#>       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
#> [1,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#> [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [3,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#> [4,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#> [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>